# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compat_mode'

Tags: python, nervana-neon

I am working on a evaluation task, I'm linking skip-thought in neon but I am getting this Attribute error.

```
pdict = dict()
        pdict['neon_version'] = __neon_version__
        compat_mode = self.be.compat_mode if self.be.compat_mode is not None else 'neon'
        pdict['backend'] = {'type': self.be.__class__.__name__,
                            'compat_mode': compat_mode,
                            'rng_seed': self.be.rng_seed,
                            'rng_state': self.be.rng_get_state()}




if 'backend' in model_dict:
            if 'compat_mode' in model_dict['backend']:
                self.be.compat_mode = model_dict['backend']['compat_mode']
```

Here the evaluation project im using is in python 2.7 version and neon is in python 3.6 is this any cause of this error?

Here is the exception trace

```
/Projects/ronin$ python Retrieval-Eval.py
No handlers could be found for logger "gensim.models.doc2vec"
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
<module 'posixpath' from '/home/pratyusha/.virtualenvs/ronin/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
2018-02-26 12:06:32,625 - neon - DISPLAY - dataset files /home/pratyusha/Projects/neon/examples/skipthought/output/doc__books_txt_1_.h5 and vocabulary file /home/pratyusha/Projects/neon/examples/skipthought/output/doc__books_txt_1_.vocab already exist. will use cached data. 
2018-02-26 12:06:32,626 - neon - DISPLAY - 
Vocab size from the dataset is: 252
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 482, in <module>
    e = evaluate(dialogue, dtype="str", concept_weight=1.0, task_weight=0)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 248, in evaluate
    retrieval2 = get_skipsim_matches(selected=questions, dtype="str", conceptW=concept_weight, taskW=task_weight)  #HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 444, in get_skipsim_matches
    conceptDictionary = get_skipsim_concept_dictionary(selected[1:], dtype)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 462, in get_skipsim_concept_dictionary
    scores = get_list_skipsim_scores(selected, dialogue, dtype)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 428, in get_list_skipsim_scores
    score = st.get_sim_score(q1, q2)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 131, in get_sim_score
    a = self.get_sentence_vec(text1)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 79, in get_sentence_vec
    model = load_sent_encoder(model_dict)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/neon/examples/skipthought/util.py", line 367, in load_sent_encoder
    model_train = Model(model_dict)
  File "/home/pratyusha/.virtualenvs/ronin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neon/models/model.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.deserialize(layers, load_states=(not weights_only))
  File "/home/pratyusha/.virtualenvs/ronin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neon/models/model.py", line 469, in deserialize
    self.be.compat_mode = model_dict['backend']['compat_mode']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compat_mode'
```

Thank you

Comment: `self.be` is `None`, like the error message says. You didn't post any of the code where you initialized `self.be`, so there's no way to guess why that happened.

Comment: @kindall In above mentioned code  self.be.compat_mode = model_dict['backend']['compat_mode'] self.be is initialized there.

Comment: You can't assign to `self.be.compat_mode` before you assign to `self.be`. Such an assignment is equivalent to `setattr(self.be, 'compat_mode', model_dict['backend']['compat_mode'])`, so `self.be` needs to exist first.

Comment: @pyral17 that line does not initialise `self.be`, it only initialises `self.be.compat_mode` if `self.be` is already there. What is `self`? Please post more of your code.